# Netbeans 8.0.2 Output Window

Tags: background-color, netbeans-8

I would like to change the output window color from the default white to black or some other color. I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 IDE.

Comment: is there a specific reason you have for doing so?

Comment: yes I am doing a rk4 integration simulator in C/C++ and I need to be able to see show all of the steps for learning purposes. I've searched google everywhere and still cannot find an answer.

Answer (score 13):

You can do by following methods:

Make sure your output window is visible - if it's not, just run any of your application and close it again - the window will pop up right after running it.

All you have to do now is to right click into the output window and choose Settings. That's it, a window where you can customize all the font colors and background colors will show up.
Below Image for reference: you can go Tools-->Option-->Miscellaneous-->Output

[image: For reference you can go Tools-->Option-->Miscellaneous-->Output]

Comment: That worked in windows. I went to tools->options->miscellaneous->output and changed the background color. :)

Comment: great..accept answer if you feel this is right answer for you question.  So, it would help some.

Answer (score 2):

This Questions was resolved by Dipak D Desai.

## Resolution Steps:

1. make sure your output window is visible
2. go to:
   tools->options->miscellaneous->output

and you can change your output window(s) as you desire. Again thumbs up for Dipak everyone :)